# Printing Image, Text and Margins?

Tags: vb.net, printing

I spent few days trying and looking for `Vb.net` script that can combine the three (Printing Image + Printing Text + changing Margins); but no luck;

### I want to:

- Print image in `PictureBox1`;
- Print text from `RichTextBox1` (below OR above the image);
- Adjust the page **margins**;

Also, I appreciate it if I can get help to **Print-Preview** the above before printing;

Below is my start up script that will only manipulate the text:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    printDocument1.Print()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1
    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles printDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim fnt_t As Font
    fnt_t = RichTextBox1.Font
    e.Graphics.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, fnt_t, New SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 10)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I started with the code below; which is working for printing and print Preview the texts; then I started messing up to add the images and control margins, but it did not work;

Comment: I started with the code below; which is working for printing and print Preview the texts; then I started messing up to add the images and control margins, but it did not work;    Oh; I just run into problem that I cannot Paste my code; it said more characters than allowed??

Comment: OK; I figured another way to post the code; I am not sure if this is the only way; but I end up posting it in the original question above...

Comment: use e.Graphics.Drawimage to put an image in your printdoc ..

Comment: hi matzone; would you kindly post a sample code for my request?

Comment: try this thread .. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/7b3d3a41-544e-4050-9010-850e7db77d01/drawimage-and-drawstring-missing

Comment: I've tried it, it is helpful, but the problem is that it always puts the Image on top of text; I would like to do the opposite; is it possible?

Comment: I think if you did drawstring after drawimage will put text above the image ...

Comment: I've already tried that and it didn't work!!

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Hi Mark; not yet; I was successful in putting the picture in front (it seems the default of VB.Net), but could not figure out how to put it behind the text. Like, I wanted to draw the picture and some text on top of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is based on your comment on wanting to draw text on your image.

When you are drawing items to the PrintDocument the one that is drawn first will be underneath any item that is drawn later, if they are occupying the same location on the Graphic surface. This is an example on how to center text in the Image.

```
Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage     
    Dim fnt_t As Font = RichTextBox1.Font 'Set your font
    Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), PictureBox1.Image.Size) ' used to give a common reference
    Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat()
    fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center 'Horizontal Centering
    fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center 'Vertical Centering
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox1.Image, rect) 'Draw Image
    e.Graphics.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, fnt_t, New SolidBrush(Color.White), rect, fmt) 'Draw Text
End Sub
```

[image]

And this example is how to add text to the bottom of the image.

```
Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim fnt_t As Font = RichTextBox1.Font 'Set your font
    Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), PictureBox1.Image.Size) ' get the size of the image
    Dim lineheight As Integer = TextRenderer.MeasureText(RichTextBox1.Text, fnt_t).Height ' Measure to find height of text
    Dim stringRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, rect.Bottom - lineheight, rect.Width, lineheight) 'Determine rectangle for Text 
    Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat() 'Tell it to center Text in its rectangle 
    fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center 'Center it 
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox1.Image, rect) 'Draw Image
    e.Graphics.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, fnt_t, New SolidBrush(Color.White), stringRect, fmt) 'Draw Text
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: WONDERFUL; Works perfect; I could not find this anywhere in all search engines; Thanks Mark.